# What does KeyMembers contain?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does the **EntityType.KeyMembers** property contain just the primary key, or also unique keys and foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from the entity framework team on twitter. I am told that it contains unique keys and primary keys.